Spring security with vaadin login
I have 2 classes that contains user password and roles. I have my own userDetailsService that get the user password and roles with the username and return an objet User with the username, password and Set of grantedauthorities qith all the roles of the user.
But i cant manage to login i tried a lot of thing and dont know how to proceed.
i have
package com.example.application.security;

import com.example.application.data.Persona;
import com.example.application.data.PersonaRepository;
import com.example.application.data.Rol;
import com.example.application.data.RolRepository;
import com.example.application.services.CrmService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.*;

@Servicepublic class TribunalesUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired    private CrmService crm;

    @Override    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        PersonaRepository personaRepository = crm.getPersonaRepository();
        RolRepository rolRepository = crm.getRolRepository();

        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorityList = new HashSet<>();
        List<Persona> p = personaRepository.search(username);
        Iterator<Persona> it = p.iterator();
        if(it.hasNext()){
            Persona persona = it.next();
            List<Rol> roles = rolRepository.search(persona.getUsuario());
            for (Rol rol : roles) {
                authorityList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(rol.getCodigo()));
            }

            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(persona.getUsuario(), persona.getContrasena(), authorityList);

        }else{
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Usuario no encontrado");
        }
    }
}

And the securityConfig
package com.example.application.security;

import com.example.application.views.LoginView;
import com.vaadin.flow.spring.security.VaadinWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@EnableWebSecurity@Configurationpublic class SecurityConfig extends VaadinWebSecurity {

    @Autowired    private TribunalesUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                auth.requestMatchers(
                        AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher(HttpMethod.GET, "/images/*.png")).permitAll());
        super.configure(http);
        setLoginView(http, LoginView.class);
    }


    @Bean    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean    public UserDetailsService users() {
        return userDetailsService;
    }
}

I tried logging whit plain text, bcrypt password bcrypt with {bcrypt}before the hash and nothing resulted

What exactly is the problem? Errors, stacktraces, org.springframework.securty-Debug-Level-Logs, ... please.

I got this log from a single try @cfrick  https://justpaste.it/dcjai

Oh i got it and fixed, i was missing the DaoAuthenticationProvider problem fixed

Sad to see questions without answers :(. So if anyone is stuck here, or searching for this, may be worth looking into these materials:
Enabling security for Vaadin applications:

https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/security/enabling-security

And probably you end up needing to write your security provider, and then these materials could be handy:

https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture (official SPring doc)
https://dzone.com/articles/spring-security-authentication (more hands-on article)

If there is a concrete question you can just always comment here or open a new StackOverFlow question.
